# Ubuntu start hangs (Nouveau / iwlwifi)

Tags: 13.10, startup, nouveau, iwlwifi

I tried to install Ubuntu 13.10 on my XPS 15 Haswell.

The hardware is:

> Intel i7 4702HQ (+Intel HD Graphics 4600)
>
> Nvidia GT550M
>
> 16GB RAM
>
> 512GB mSATA SSD

I had already Win 8.1 installed and tried to create a dualboot system.
The installer did only launch with the "nomodeset" option, else I got a blackscreen after the splash. Installing was possible without problems then.

But now I can't boot into the graphical inteface. Without "nomodeset" it hangs on loading the nouveau driver. When I set the "nomodeset" option in GRUB it hangs on loading iwlwifi:

> 9.730405 iwlwifi 0000:006:00:0: No association and the time event is already over...
>
> 13.861085 iwlwifi 0000:006:00:0: No association and the time event is already over...
>
> ...

Can you help me please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably it is due to missing driver for your graphics card.
You could install bumblebee to solve this issue.

Comment: Anytime mate :)